# $A$ be a non zero skew-symmetric matrix of even order

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Given that $A$ is a non-zero skew symmetric even order matrix.Then which od following is true

> $1).$$Ax=0$ has infinitely many solutions
>
> $2).$$Ax=\lambda x$ has solution for every non-zero $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $3).$$Ax=\lambda x$ has  unique solution for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R^{*}}$
>
> $4).$ $Ax=\lambda x$ may not have unique solution for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

**The solution I Tried**-Given matrix is of even order so by property of skew-symmetric matrix it may or may not have determinent zero.so option **1** is discarded

Rest of options are making me confuse because in these options $\lambda $ is not eigenvalues and $x$ is not eigenfunction,How to think further Please help

Thank you

Comment: 2 is clearly true ($x=0$ is a solution for any $\lambda$). 3 is false unless $\lambda = 0$ is the only eigenvalue. 4 is true for any $\lambda$ that is an eigenvalue. Counterexample for 1 is $A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, which is invertible, hence $Ax = 0 \iff x=0$.

Comment: okk the answer  for option 3 and 4 is on the basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: $Ax = \lambda x$ has a non-unique solution if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue. The equation always has $x=0$ as a solution. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then by definition there is also a nonzero solution (let $x$ be any eigenvector associated with $\lambda$). Any scalar multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, hence if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then the equation has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: ''$Ax=λx$ has a non-unique solution if and only if λ is an eigenvalue''. Never heard about this,i will add this line in my notes ,Thank you for you valuable answer.